# submitting pre filled form in vue js

Tags: forms, vue.js

The form is this one.

```
<div v-if="formhide">
                  <form="dbadmin_login_form" method="post" action="https://example.com/#abc:db=rohit_one_test" id="myform" name="login_form" target="_blank">' +
                    <div class="item">'
                    <input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" value="rohit_one_test">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                    <input type="password" name="pma_password" id="input_password" value="test123">
                    <input type="submit" id="input_go" value="Go">
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

The method for submitting is this

```
popup(){
     console.log($("#myform").submit());
     $("#myform").submit();
  }
```

log can be seen on console but nothing happens.

@Edit code

The HTML Part

```
              <form  v-if="formhide" method="post" :action="pma_posturl" ref="myform" name="login_form" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" :value="pma_username">
                <input type="password" name="pma_password" id="input_password" :value="pma_password">
              </form>
```

The value initalization part

```
export default{
  data: function(){
    return{
    pma_username: '',
    pma_password: '',
    pma_posturl: "example.com",
    pma_dbname:'',
    formhide:false,
```

// the form submission part

```
popup(){
     this.pma_username=this.credentials.database;
     this.pma_password=this.credentials.password;
     this.pma_posturl=this.pma_posturl+this.credentials.database;

     this.$refs.myform.submit();
  }
```

when the page refresh and popup method is called the value of input field remains what was set in initialization time.
on second time it update the corresponding value.how to fix this.

Comment: What's supposed to happen? Plus, I can't see your `popup` method being used in your template. Also, you should avoid using jQuery with Vue, because Vue and jQuery use different DOM manipulation techniques.

Comment: @dziraf it should open the url in new tab. popup method is being called from somewhere else.this.$refs.myform is returning undefined for some reason so i used the given one.

Comment: There is no `ref="myform"` in your form element, so it's normal that `this.$refs.myform` returns undefined.

Comment: @dziraf code update as you suggested. please see the new issue.

Comment: Try to `console.log` your credentials in your popup method. Also, since you're accessing them via `this`, where are they defined?

Comment: @dziraf i can successfully console log the credentials.those are defined and populated just fine ,as i can submit the form 2nd time successfully. and those form value are set  to empty/whatever listed in data function in first run.